# Doxygen does not find files when specifying Source directory

Tags: doxygen

---

Hello,

I try to use doxygen to generate code documentation from a set of folders. My folder structure is like this:

```
+root
+-include/
+-include/subdir/file.h
+-src
+-src/subdir/file.cpp
+-Documentation/doxygen.config
```

Then in the configuration file I have the following settings in the "default" configuration file (Which is stated in the documentation and other questions here):

```
INPUT                  = "../include" "../src"
RECURSIVE              = YES
```

The problem is that when running this configuration, the HTML output does not contain any documentation whatsoever. When I add all individual files like

```
INPUT  = "../include/subdir/file.h"
```

to the input, it does generate documentation for those files. Is there an additional setting in the default configuration that I need to include in order for doxygen to find the files and create documentation?

I'm using doxygen 1.8.4 on Linux Ubuntu (12.04 LTS).

Thanks in advance for any hints or tips.

Comment: I tend not to use RECURSIVE myself as it tends to bring in too much.  However, what happens if you (a) specify the folder path i.e. ../include/subdir, with recursive off, and/or (b) try ../include and ../src without the quotes?  Shouldn't make any difference but comparing your and my doxyfiles that's all the comes to mind.

Comment: Today I faced similar issue as you describe and the problem was in `FILE_PATTERNS` setting. After I cleared it, `doxygen` would operate as expected.

Comment: @jcxz well I tried your FILE_PATTERNS trick and it did not work for me... I still have to list all the directories...

Comment: Your INPUT paths are specified relative to the directory containing the Doxygen configuration file.  Is this also the directory in which you are invoking Doxygen?  Doxygen may be resolving the relative paths from the PWD rather than the directory containing the configuration file.  Also, remember that header files need the '@file' directive to be included in the documentation - this may be bypassed if the file is explicitly listed in the INPUT option (?).

Answer (score 11):

You can just simply do `../root` instead of declaring both `../include` and `../src`

Also make sure you don't put quotes around the full absolute path, for it works just fine without those.

Make sure recursive is set to YES as you did.

Putting in the directory to the INPUT tag worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you still need this, but I have been struggling with this for some time and found the solution (at least for me)!

Leave the **INPUT** empty and set the **RECURSIVE** tag to **YES**. I am not an expert maybe someone else that knows these tags better can give a better answer, I just stumbled on the solution

At the very top of your source files, place:

```
/// \file
```

This tells Doxygen to include it in the HTML and it will show up in the files tab.