# How can I document with doxygen my cpp functions?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm having troubles with `doxygen` to document my `cpp` files, I have already `.h` well documented.

My problem is that my `main.cpp` which is in the main directory of the project is fine, I can see it in the `html` with all the information, but the rest `.cpp` files that are in the `/src` subdirectory only appear in the `html` with the dependency graph and the source code but not the body functions for example.
I have all the functions of the project documented in the `.h` but with brief introduction and I want to explain more about them.

I think it is a bit rare situation and I haven't found anything like this here, hope you can help me?

This is the structure of the project:

[image: Structure]

This is my doxyfile config:

```
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.cpp *.json *.h
INPUT                  = Ejemplo Folder 
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.cpp *.json *.h
RECURSIVE              = YES
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
DOT_PATH               = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe"
```

This is how my `main` looks in the `html` generated with its functions:

[image: Main]

And this is what other file in the subdirectories looks:

[image: Other file]

Comment: What do you have in the "INPUT = " part of the config? Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472320/how-to-set-an-input-directory-for-doxygen

Comment: Two folders, one contains the main and a configuration file (which is well documented as the main) and the other one with the /src and /include

Comment: Dont tell us, _show_ us. [Edit] your question to provide the relevant part of your `Doxyfile`.

Comment: Place the image verbatim in the question, not as a link to an image. Tell us where you start doxygen (including arguments), where your Doxyfile resides and the differences of your Doxyfile compared to the standard Doxyfile as obtained by `doxygen -g` (careful it will overwrite an existing file with the same name).

Comment: Sorry I can't add any image I'm new and it only let me put it as a link

Comment: What is 'Folder', the line you made blue? Try to add in the `main.cpp` a comment block with `\file`.

Comment: Yes Folder is the first blue line, I did it but nothing happens

Comment: You already gave the changes in the `Doxyfile`, but where is this file located in your tree (and is the name `Doxyfile` or something else). Where do you start doxygen and with which command and arguments?

Comment: My Doxyfile has other name "config_document" and it's located in the same level as Ejemplo and Folder. The command I run is "doxygen config_document".

Comment: That looks OK. Reread the question so the problem is only with the files in the "blue line part". To get a bit further please try to set `ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC` to `YES`. Also look at the Other `EXTRACT_..` options in the `Doxyfile` and just set them yo `YES`

Comment: It doesn't work, I've updated the Doxyfile as you told me but it's the same result.

Comment: Hmm... The "blue line" Folder does not have spaces or other special characters in it (I can see an _ but that is OK). Btw which version of Doxygen are you using (looks reasonable recent)? I would say create a small example that also shows the problem make the file available in one way or another as I think there is a problem somewhere in the communication.